# Always bind our SQL statements?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have been researching into PDO's bindValue(). I know that preparing my SQL statements with PDO is keeping SQL injections from happening.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id AND title = :title');
$stmt->bindValue(':id', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':title', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

By binding the ID as a number, and the Title was a string, we can limit the damage done when someone tries to do an SQL injection within the code.

Should we always bind our values with a PDO::PARAM_ so we can limit what can be pulled from the database in an SQL injection? Does this add more security with PDO when doing our bindValue()?

Comment: The types are more to keep you from shooting yourself on the knee, rather than for security.

Comment: your `bindValue` example is wrong

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)